# How to Harvest Gaspods in Subnautica?

Tags: subnautica

In Subnautica, how do you harvest the Gaspods from the [Gasopod](http://subnautica.wikia.com/wiki/Gasopod) creature?

I have only noticed these creatures doing two particular things: looking beautiful from afar, or being painful while up close.  And now that I have a torpedo launcher, I need to harvest these little "gas pod" things to make the necessary Gas Torpedo ammo.

How do I harvest this? Because the gas explosion just looks like unselectable dust.

Answer (score 9):

You swim near them, they then emit small yellow balls. If you are quick enough, you can grab those balls before they explode and harm you.

It is as simple as that. Get the [Ultra Glide Fins](http://subnautica.wikia.com/wiki/Ultra_Glide_Fins) so that you are fast, plus a Seaglide, and just provoke them to release the gas pods. Then grab them before they explode, and if you can't get all pods, run away quickly enough to not get damaged by the gas cloud.

With practice, this becomes fairly easy and quite safe.

Comment: It's never entirely safe, first because the toxins linger for quite a long time so you're likely to get into an almost-dispersed cloud, and then gasopods are often in a group, so as you chase pods from one, you may get bombarded by another from above or a side without you noticing. But it's not easy to die that way, and you'd be hard-pressed to find an application for more than a couple pods anyway.

Comment: @SF. I never had any problems with that. Just stay moving. There is no need to linger near them. Get close, grab a pod, get out. If you stay between them for long periods, sure, you can get blind-sided. But why risk that? You can grab enough pods either way, you don't need them in the hundreds. A couple are more then enough.

Comment: Then turn back for another run and run into a cloud from the previous one. Or get forced to change directions due to a jihadfish.

Comment: @SF. The cloud disperses fairly quickly. And in the safe shallows, there is no predator you need to avoid. The crashfish is only found in the tunnels below, you shouldn't have any of them triggering while going for gasopods. With a little bit of planning and patience its very safe.

Comment: Not my experience with the cloud. And the crashfish often lives at edges of caverns that exit into basins where gasopods love to linger.

Comment: @SF. I would suggest staying close to the surface. There is absolutely no need to hug the sea floor. You can dive down, grab a pod and escape to the side while going up. Moreover, with glide fins and seaglide you are faster then crashfish, if you hear one trigger just stay moving, it can't catch up and it doesn't have an unlimited range, it stops after some time. Sure, it does cost you a bit of time to evade one, but its not like you are in a hurry, getting a few for a complete load of torpedoes is still a matter of minutes, even when taking precautions.